# Allow cookies to be used from different origin subdomain

Tags: http, cookies, subdomain

If the url on my browser's address bar is `dev.example.com` and if I make a request to `sub1.dev.example.com` which responds with set-cookie with the following properties:

- httpOnly
- secure
- no same-site attribute (defaults to lax)
- Domain=dev.example.com

While still on `dev.example.com`, if I call `sub2.dev.example.com`, the cookie is sent over in the request, which is what I'm expecting.

But, if the url on my browser's address bar is `sub3.dev.example.com` and I call `sub2.dev.example.com`, the cookie is not sent.

(verified on chrome 92 and firefox 90)

Is there any way to send a cookie to `sub2.dev.example.com` while on origin `sub3.dev.example.com`, where the specific cookie was set in request response from `sub1.dev.example.com` while on origin `dev.example.com` ?

Or even better, to allow a cookie to be sent to all subdomains of `**.dev.example.com` while on any origin subdomain of `**.dev.example.com` independently of the origin that originally requested or set the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing some more, it looks like I forgot to add the "withCredentials" flag on my request.

For anyone who stumbled upon this, make sure you set "withCredentials" to true on your calls if you are using axios or "credentials: 'include'" if you are using fetch.